# How to pass variables from one template to another in Jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2, tornado

As specified in the title, my concern is about how to pass a variable set in a parent Jinja2 template to its child template.

The configuration of the project is the following:

- I'm using Tornado to build an API.
- In the `app.py` script, I associated the endpoint `/parent` to the
  class `ParentHandler`. When a curl GET method is performed, the `get()`
  method of the class `ParentHandler` is executed and renders its result,
  `response` (which is a dict) to the template `parent.html`. I would like to use the rendered HTML code as a header for
  the child template, so at the end of `parent.html`, there is a block to
  display the tags from the child template.
- In `app.py`, I associated the endpoint `'/child'` to the class `ChildHanlder`. When a curl GET method is performed, the `get()` method of the class `ChildHandler` is executed and renders its result, `child_content` (which is a dict) to the template `child.html` (I'm not getting `ParentHandler`'s `response` in `ChildHandler`, so `ChildHandler` renders only `child_content`). The template `child.html` includes `parent.html`, so the behavior I'm expecting is `child.html` to display the HTML code from `parent.html` (with the values from the dict `response` provided by `ParentHandler`, not `ChildHandler`) and to render its own dict, `child_content`.

Unfortunately, when I try to perform the described process above, `child.html` doesn't find `response` from `parent.py`.

Here's a code snippet:

app.py

```
class Application(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        handlers = [
            (r'/parent', ParentHandler),
            (r'/child', ChildHandler)
        ]

        jinja_load = Jinja2Loader(os.path.join(PATH, '/templates'))
        settings = {
            'template_path': os.path.join(PATH, '/templates')
            'template_loader': jinja_load
        }
        tornado.web.Application.__init__(self, handlers, **settings)
```

parent.py

```
class ParentHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        response = {"status": "200", "val": "some_value"}
        try:
            self.render("parent.html", response=response)
        except:
            self.write(response)
```

child.py

```
class ChildHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        response = {"status": "200", "data": "some_data"}
        try:
            self.render("child.html", child_content=response)
        except:
            self.write(response)
```

parent.html

```
<div>
    {% if response['status'] == 200 %}
        {% set val1 = response.get('val', 0) %}
        <i>{{ val1 }}</i>
    {% endif %}
</div>
{% block child_content %}{% endblock %}
```

child.html

```
{% include 'parent.html' %} 
{% from 'parent.html' import val1 %} 
{% block child_content %}
<table>
{% for d in data %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ d }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

But I end up with this error when I try to render child.html:

```
UndefinedError: 'response' is undefined
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add the `with` keyword to the include statement, like so:

```
{% include 'parent.html' with var1=value1, var2=value2, ... %}
```

In your case

```
{% include 'parent.html' with response=responseValue %}
```

Comment: Thing is I'm not getting responsValue from child.py, but from parent.py :/
I would like to pass responseValue from the parent to the child.

Comment: The error you are getting means you are trying to use the variable named ```response``` in the parent without it having a value. This works quite similar to standard inheritance, when you render ```child.html``` you also render ```parent.html```, but when the parent is trying to execute: ```{% if response['status'] == 200 %} ``` it finds that ```response``` has no value because the variable has not been initialized (which must be done through the entry point, the child).

Comment: Correct me if I didn't understand properly but, are you trying to pass some value generated in ```parent.html``` into ```child.html```?

Comment: Yes, exactly, I'm trying to pass a value generated in `parent.html` into `child.html`.
But if I understand your previous comment, the only way around would be to initialize `response` in `child.py` as well?

Comment: Regarding the ```response``` value issue, If your function renders the template ```child.html``` and it includes ```parent.html``` if you want to send parameters to ```parent.html``` you need to send them how I showed in the answer above. Although if the ```response``` variable is being sent from the render function context parameter I believe every included template can access it.
As for the second issue, I'm going to expand the answer.

Comment: I think I have misunderstood one thing regarding your code: When you call the render function, what template are you rendering, ```parent.html``` or ```child.html```?

Comment: I'm trying to render in `child.html` only. Sorry, I believe my explanation wasn't clear enough. I have updated the original post with more details

Answer (score 0):

I ended up giving up my original idea and decided to go with @Strinnityk 's solution. 
I changed the output of `child.py` and updated it with the output of `parent.py`.
That way, I don't even need to use variables in the `child.html` template.

Thanks again!

Comment: Oh, sorry, was quite busy yesterday and couldn't keep on helping. Is it working? Can I help you with anything?